# R collapse date fields with conditions

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df=data.frame(c(1,2,2,2,3,4,4),
as.Date(c("2015-01-29","2015-02-02","2015-02-02","2015-02-02","2014-05-04","2014-05-04","2014-05-04")),
as.Date(c( "2010-10-01","2009-09-01","2014-01-01","2014-02-01","2009-01-01","2014-03-01","2013-03-01")),
as.Date(c("2016-04-30","2013-12-31","2014-01-31","2016-04-30","2014-02-28","2014-08-31","2013-05-01"))); 
names(df)=c('id','poi','start','end')

> df
  id        poi      start        end
1  1 2015-01-29 2010-10-01 2016-04-30
2  2 2015-02-02 2009-09-01 2013-12-31
3  2 2015-02-02 2014-01-01 2014-01-31
4  2 2015-02-02 2014-02-01 2016-04-30
5  3 2014-05-04 2009-01-01 2014-02-28
6  4 2014-05-04 2014-03-01 2014-08-31
7  4 2014-05-04 2013-03-01 2013-05-01
```

The start and end dates are insurance begin and end dates, sometimes there are same start dates  for multiple rows because they 
pertain to different insurance types. I am interested in retaining those IDs that has consistent insurance 
coverage one year before and after the poi. Each ID can only have 1 poi.

My output would be a list of IDs that have insurance coverage 1 year pre and 1 year post the  poi. In this case it would exlude ids 3 and 4 becuase they dont have coverage 1 year after poi.

```
  ids=c(1,2)
```

I have tried the following, but honestly have no idea about how I can achieve what I want.

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
library(rehape2)
df.melt=melt(df,
             id=c("id","poi"))

df.melt=mutate(df.melt, flag=ave(id,id,variable,FUN=seq_along))
df.melt=mutate(df.melt, variable=paste(variable,flag,sep ="_"))
df.cast=dcast(df.melt, id+poi~variable)
```

Comment: what exactly would be your expected result?

Comment: @agenis I have fixed the question to include the expected output. thanks!

Comment: @user3641630 so am I clear that you want a list of POI's where the begging date and ending date are greater than one year away from the POI?

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim it would include the IDs that have beginning and ending date that are one year from the POI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evaluate the rows individually, with `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# filter to only rows with a POI within the desired range
df %>% filter(poi - years(1) >= start, 
              poi + years(1) <= end)

#   id        poi      start        end
# 1  1 2015-01-29 2010-10-01 2016-04-30
# 2  2 2015-02-02 2014-02-01 2016-04-30
```

If you'd rather evaluate all the rows for one ID, maybe something like

```
# group to summarize IDs separately
df %>% group_by(id, poi) %>% 
    # collapse rows to min start and max end for each ID
    summarise(start = min(start), 
              end = max(end)) %>% 
    # filter to only rows with a POI within the desired range
    filter(poi - years(1) >= start, 
           poi + years(1) <= end)

# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
# Groups: id [2]
# 
#      id        poi      start        end
#   (dbl)     (date)     (date)     (date)
# 1     1 2015-01-29 2010-10-01 2016-04-30
# 2     2 2015-02-02 2009-09-01 2016-04-30
```

Such an approach would overlook gaps in coverage, though, if that's a possibility. If so, `lubridate::interval` and `int_overlaps` may be useful in condensing rows carefully.

Comment: I need to take coverage gap into consideration as well. Thank you, this gives me a really good platform to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, but if it doesn't, you should be able to just play with the greater than and less than signs:

```
 df[(df$poi-df$start)/365>1&(df$end-df$poi)/365>1,]

 > df[(df$poi-df$start)/365>1&(df$end-df$poi)/365>1,]
   id        poi      start        end
 1  1 2015-01-29 2010-10-01 2016-04-30
 4  2 2015-02-02 2014-02-01 2016-04-30
```

This gives you the two lines of the df that hold the value you want..

Now just the id's:

```
 df$id[(df$poi-df$start)/365>1&(df$end-df$poi)/365>1]
 df$id[(df$poi-df$start)/365>1&(df$end-df$poi)/365>1]
 [1] 1 2
```